# using values only known at apply time in nested for_each loop

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am very new to Terraform, so excuse me if I miss something obvious!

I am building a project to help me understand how Terraform works, and part of this is trying to make the config as dynamic as possible within the modules.  The "project" is essentially to create 4 VMs, then create an Application Gateway and split them into two backend pools and route based on the URL path.
To extrapolate the network interface ID (created in another module and provided through an output variable) and matching the VMs to the correct backend pool, I have created a map containing the pool name, the path, and a list of member VMs; then through a nested for loop in the locals.tf file I have created a new map containing a flattened list of the VMs, the backend pool name and key, and the network interface id (pulled from the output from the vnic creation above, indexed by the pool key).
I have tested this using static variables firstly, and got this to work great, but now i've put it into the "real world" project, it errors, saying:

**The "for_each" set includes values derived from resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the full set of keys that will identify the instances of this resource.**

**When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to use a map value where the keys are defined statically in your configuration and where only the values contain apply-time results.**

**Alternatively, you could use the -target planning option to first apply only the resources that the for_each value depends on, and then apply a second time to fully converge.**

I have provided the code below

```
*[defined variables, app gateway module]*
backend_pools = {
        be_pool_01 : {
            bep_name = "BE_Pool_01"
            bep_path = "images"
            bep_members = ["appvm01", "appvm02"]
        }
        be_pool_02 : {
            bep_name = "BE_Pool_02"
            bep_path = "videos"
            bep_members = ["appvm03", "appvm04"]
        }
    }

*[output from virtual machines module]*
output "vmnics" {
    value = azurerm_network_interface.vmnic
}

*[locals.tf, app gateway module]*
backend_nics = distinct(flatten([
        for poolkey,poolvalues in var.backend_pools : [
            for nickey,nicvalues in var.imported_nics : {
                pool_key = poolkey
                nic_key = nickey
                be_pool_name = poolvalues.bep_name
                be_pool_path = poolvalues.bep_path
                vm_nic_name = nicvalues.name
                vm_nic_id = nicvalues.id
                vm_nic_ipconfig_name = nicvalues.ip_configuration[0].name
            } if contains(poolvalues.bep_members,nickey)
        ]
    ]))

*[main.tf, app gateway module : main resource config that produces the error]*
resource "azurerm_network_interface_application_gateway_backend_address_pool_association" "appgwnicassoc01" {
    for_each = local.backend_nics
        backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_application_gateway.appgateway01[each.value.pool_key].backend_address_pool_id
        network_interface_id    = each.value.vm_nic_id
        ip_configuration_name   = each.value.vm_nic_ipconfig_name
}
```

To explain the construct; I have a number of modules to perform specific tasks; a network module to create the network core infra (vnet/subnet/nsg etc), a virtual machine module, which creates the VMs and their associated interfaces and the app gateway module. The vm module outputs the virtual interfaces, which is then used within the app gateway module (via a map variable) to (try) and create the app gateway and routing. because the only way i can see to tie the virtual networks and the backend pools together is by using a nested for loop, i have created the new map in locals.tf.  It is the app gateway module that produces this error.

Because I need the id's of the network interfaces created at apply time, I can't see a way round this other than using their suggestion of using the -target planning option to create the required resources first, but this seems the wrong way to do it. Can anyone offer any advice or suggestions? I've never seen this error before, but I am assuming I am seeing this because i'm creating a local variable using the output from a module?  normal config uses this sort of dependency all the time, so it's a bit confusing why this is happening - any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Would you mind separating the error so it's obvious when someone reads the question? Also, it would be great to explain what is the correlation between different modules.

Comment: I've revised my post to (hopefully) make everything a bit clearer!